# Qt: Help to choice the multimedia framework

Tags: qt, multimedia

Please give me peace of advice. I would like to create some kind of audio-video player with some original functionality. But the problem is I'm not sure which multimedia framework to use. I tried to use Phonon but it has some bugs and for some reason it doesn't support many file formats (maybe I just don't know how to use it properly). So I'm thinking maybe some other mediaframework would be better. Maybe I'm wrong. I can use only LGPL license.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which OS:es do you need to support?

Comment: To Macke: every OS that Qt supports.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Google for "qt vlc". That might give you a starting point.

Comment: As far as I know vlc is under GPL that means it cannot be used in the commercial project.

Answer (score 0):

Like the above user said, vlc is a good option.
Another good option would be GStreamer. Although it isn't qt-specific (it's rather Gnome-y actually), it's a pretty decent multimedia framework, and its documentation is (in my humble opinion) superior to vlc's.
Check them out at: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/

Comment: IIRC, On Linux, Qt's Phonon uses GStreamer behind the walls. (QuickTime on Mac and DirectShow on Windows)